# Getting response from Alamofire like this Object [object Object] has no split method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

I am new to swift. I want to parse a graphql webservice where I prepared one string by using alamofire I passed string like the below.

I am getting JSON response fine when run on simulator 5,6 and 6+, but when checked on real time devices iPhone6+ it is working fine and when checked on iPhone6 I am getting error like this:

> Object [object Object] has no split  method.

Here is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mywebsite.com/post-request", parameters: [:], encoding: .Custom({
        (convertible, params) in
        var mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableRequest.HTTPBody = "myBodyString".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)Alamofire.request(.POST, url)
    .response {
        (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
           }
        return (mutableRequest, nil)
    }))
```

Comment: Your code doesn't really make any sense. You shouldn't be using a `.Custom` encoding without any parameters. What are you trying to POST?

Comment: I am passing content type in the parameters in the above code I did not mentioned sorry for  that  and "myBodyString"  is nothing but string what i prepared to post